# ImportError: No module named IPython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

When i try to use **from IPython.display import clear_output, display_html**, then i show the error:

[image: Error Image]
(ImportError: No module named IPython)

I am using Python 2.7.13, and im trying to make the game of life from John Conway. I am following this link: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/Life.ipynb

I have read another questions and answers about it, but any answer works for me. First, this error is showed in command line, and when i try to run this code in a file. Second, this error is direct to IPython, not submodule or something similiar.

Comment: Which IPython version do you have? Can you check with running in  terminal `ipython --version`

Comment: Have you installed ipython? `pip install ipython`

Comment: Try typing 'jupyter qtconsole' and see if an iPython terminal opens.  If so it will tell you that ipython is installed and it will list version number.

Comment: Ok. I checked **ipython --version** but i havent it in my computer. Then, i wrote **pip install ipython**, but i got this error:

Comment: Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\johathan\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-livxvv\\scandir\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\johathan\appdata\local\temp\pip-fqwttt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\johathan\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-livxvv\scandir\

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ok, finally i achieved my goal.

1. I wrote **ipython --version** but i found, it was not installed.
2. I tried to install it, with pip. I went to **C:\Python27\Scripts**, here is  pip, you can try in this directory, or add to environment variables.
3. I tried to install ipython, but i found a error

> [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

so i installed visual studio c++ 9.0, the version to python 2.7.

4. **pip install ipython**

Answer (score 31):

If you scrolled this far you may want to try:

```
import IPython
```

as opposed to `import Ipython`. Notice that 2 letters are capitalized

Comment: Lol, simple yet useful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: similarly, use `python -m IPython` from the shell

Comment: This was the problem. I was following along with a debugging tutorial and had typed a lowercase 'i'.

Answer (score 12):

This is most likely because `ipython` is not installed.

You can install it with `pip`.

```sh
pip install ipython
```

If you are using Anaconda (the full version) `ipython` comes preinstalled. If you are using Miniconda or if the ipython is deleted for some reason you can re-install with

```sh
conda install -c anaconda ipython
```

If you are using it with `jupyter`. You might want to register the `ipython` with a user.

```sh
python -m ipykernel install [--user] [--name <machine-readable-name>] [--display-name <"User Friendly Name">]
```

Reference :

1. [Official Documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/index.html)

Answer (score 11):

For Anaconda try,

```
conda install -c anaconda ipython
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this code to install the IPython library:

```
!pip install ipython
import IPython
```

Well, this works on Google Colab.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue, but it appears when I was running the script under sudo. Fast and easiest way was to install IPython under sudo.

```
sudo pip3 install IPython
```

Answer (score 2):

I am running a script that uses IPython module, in my terminal. If you are also trying to do something similar, this answer might help you.

```
!pip3 install IPython
```

Things to keep in mind:-

- 'I' and 'P' in IPython are uppercase.
- I am running the above command in python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import

> from IPython.display import Image

initially, I imported

> from IPython.display import image
> so there is Image not image

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem (that drove me crazy) is that I actually needed capitalization. The correct import after pip install is:

```
from IPython.display import display, update_display
```

etc.